# return value from array loop and match keyword (php)

Tags: php

I have an array `$headers` that looks like this and I want to extract the server name only. The problem is the data is not always in the same order so I need to search for "Server" and return its value. I imagine i need to use a loop but cant figure out how to incorporate the search.

Sample of array $headers

```
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "Server: nginx/1.6.2"
  [2]=>
  string(35) "Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 14:27:28 GMT"
  [3]=>
  string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "Connection: close"
  [5]=>
  string(25) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.7-1"
  [6]=>
  string(44) "Last-Modified: Fri, 08 May 2015 14:20:12 GMT"
}
```

I would like to extract the server name **nginx/1.6.2**

Here is my loop that I need to build upon

```
foreach ($headers as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = [
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
    "Server: nginx/1.6.2",
    "Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 14:27:28 GMT",
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "Connection: close",
    "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.7-1",
    "Last-Modified: Fri, 08 May 2015 14:20:12 GMT"
    ];

preg_match('/^Server: (.*)$/m', implode(PHP_EOL, $a), $matches);
echo $matches[1], PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
nginx/1.6.2
```

Comment: i think your array is formatted differently to how i have it.. would i need to convert it somehow first?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is only one `Server` header:

```
$result = current(preg_grep('/^Server:/', $headers));
```

You can also look at [http_parse_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php) but it takes the raw headers and not an array.  If you don't have the raw headers you can still use it maybe:

```
$result = http_parse_headers(implode("\r\n", $headers))['Server'];
```

Comment: he said data is not always in same manner. so how can you give index.

Comment: I got this warning `Notice:  Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: But `preg_grep` returns the index it found the match at.. not always 0

Comment: much better but and now it gives `Server: nginx/1.6.2` what would be the updated preg_grep to only return `nginx/1.6.2` ? basically the text after "server:"

Comment: or do we trim "server:" ?

Comment: I would use the `http_parse_headers()` if you have it.

Comment: couldnt make it work with http_parse.. so i went with `echo ltrim($result,"Server:");` seems to work